# How to create a formula in Excel to make it look like a SQL statement OUTPUT?

Tags: sql, excel-formula, excel-2010

In Excel, I'm trying to create formula that should look like this:

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING (FIELD,193,11))),     --Customer_ID
```

The fixed width is for what I'm trying to accomplish is:

```
Start: 193
End: 203
Length: 11
```

Also if the Datatype is NOT "CHAR" then it should look like this:

```
CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING (FIELD,255,8))) AS DATETIME),     --Birthday
```

Fixed width for this scenario:

```
Start: 255
End: 262
Length: 8
```

Comment: `=TRIM(MID(A1,193,11))`

Comment: Hu? Do you want is the equivalent in Excel based on what you do in SQL?

Comment: I want the output of that SQL statement in Excel. After writing the formula.

Comment: @Dave - Excel has a text import wizard.  If you can output your SQL results in some delimited form, Excel will happily load it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the main excel functions you'll need:

1. `MID(text,start_num,num_chars)` which is equivalent of the `substring(value,start_idx,len)` function in SQL
2. `TRIM(text)` which is the equivalent of `ltrim(rtrim())` in SQL
3. `DATEVALUE(date_text)` which will convert a string (representing a datetime) to a numeric excel datetime.

So, as an example, let the following be contained in the cell A1:

```
Here's a long string with an ID:12345ABCDEF and a date:2016-09-15 and finally some other stuff
```

Then, you can get the ID string `12345ABCDEF` using:

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,33,11))
```

and the datetime value `2016-09-15` using:

```
=DATEVALUE(TRIM(MID(A1,56,10)))
```

Keep in mind that datetimes in both excel and SQL are just specially formatted numbers, but they're formatted differently.  So, as with all systems, the only effective method of transferring datetimes from one system to another is through a well formed string (I've found that the only truly consistent format is ISO 8601), so it may be necessary to perform some other string formatting on your date values. In excel, once you have a numeric datetime value, you can use the cell formatting to change the display of that date and/or time to anything you'd like.